# How to append HTML elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append two HTML elements and pass it to the `after()` function in jquery:

```
$('div.masterButtons').after(function () {
    var foobar = $('<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>');
    var foobaz = $('<div>foo<div>baz</div></div>');
    return (foobar + foobaz)
    }
);
```

It prints:

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

How do I append the two elements? I am avoiding concatenating two html strings because the `div`s are far more complicated than these and I would need jquery elements to build it.

Comment: Tried using Handelbars or other templating framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both `foobar` and `foobaz` are jQuery object, you can't use `+` to add them

```js
$('div.masterButtons').after(function () {
    var foobar = $('<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>');
    var foobaz = $('<div>foo<div>baz</div></div>');
    return foobar.add(foobaz)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masterButtons"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really like having the function there, use the answer provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny . Alternatively, you could just simplify to:

```
$('div.masterButtons')
    .after('<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>')
    .after('<div>foo<div>baz</div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used .insertAfter

```
$('div.masterButtons').insertAfter('<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [jQuery .after() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/) you have many ways to do that.

```
$('div.masterButtons')
.after('<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>','<div>foo<div>baz</div></div>');
```

or

```
$('div.masterButtons')
.after('<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>')
.after('<div>foo<div>baz</div></div>');
```

or

```
var barAndBaz = ['<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>','<div>foo<div>baz</div></div>'];
$('div.masterButtons').after(barAndBaz);
```